# Trouble in python

Tags: python, windows

how can i convert a string into the dots that we find whenever we input a password on any site using python 2.7? I made my practical project and now im getting every string I input to be in form of dots. How do I remove it? Also in addition I have not used setpass() or getpass() or anything. Please help!

Comment: Please show some code to clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

This will show nothing when you type a password:

```
   import getpass

   password = getpass.getpass(prompt='Password:', stream=None)
   print("The password is:",password)
```

Output:

```
Password:
The password is: helloworld
```

As you can see it will not show what I am typing(*helloworld*)

**Note**: If you call getpass from within IDLE, the input may be done in the terminal you launched IDLE from rather than the idle window itself.